# netbeans macros - quote completion

Tags: netbeans, macros, netbeans-7

I have this netbeans macro, that simply outputs some html :

```
"<div class=\"kbox\">"insert-break
"    <div class=\"title\"></div>"insert-break
"    <div class=\"hide\">"insert-break
"    </div>"insert-break
"</div>"insert-break
```

The problem is that when I fire the macro, I get :

```
<div class=""kbox>
    <div class=""title toggle_div"></div>
    <div class=""hide">
</div>
</div>
```

The quotes autocompletion fires on the macro output and the css class names end up outside their quotes... Is there a way to stop this behaviour for macros? I don't want to turn off autocompletion...

Using Netbeans 7.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `delete-previous` after the double quotes.
In my code it looks like this:

```
"[<span class=\"" delete-previous
```

So you put one quote mark netbeans automaticaly adds second and then you delete it.